# searching duplicate words

Tags: regular-expression, search

This [page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns) says that I can find duplicate words using a regular expression.

The suggested command is

```
\(\<\w\+\>\)\_s*\<\1\>
```

What does "\w" mean here? Suppose the target pattern is "123\t123" where \t is the tab. Would the command be

```
/\(\<\1\+\>\)\t\<\1\>
```

or

```
/\(\<1\+\>\)\t\<\1\>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`:help /\w`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f/w) shows that `\w` is a regex metacharacter matching a word character -- any character that is either an underscore (`_`) or in the ranges `0-9`, `a-z`, or `A-Z`.

The example regex is parsed as

```
\(        \)                Capture the match so it can be reused later
  \<    \>      \<  \>      Match (with zero-width) beginning/end of word
    \w\+                    Match one or more word characters
            \_s*            Match zero or more whitespace characters,
                              including newlines
                  \1        Match the same text as the first capture
```

This style of search is useful when you don't exactly know the contents of whatever is going to match inside the `\( \)`.

Assuming that there's more possible variety in your suggested text to match (any 3-digit number, rather than just `123`), you could use the style of regex as follows

```
\(\d\d\d\)\t\1
```